# How can I create an animation with a transparent background in the Material viewport?

Tags: rendering, animation, opengl

Sorry if this is a repeat. I've had a lot of trouble explaining or putting this into words.
Basically, I want to make an animation with a transparent background, but I want it to render with the appearance of the Material Viewport.
I've been told that OpenGL is the best way to go about this, but I can't find any options for transparency in cycles for OpenGL.

I was able to create a transparent background in the typical Rendered view, but not in OpenGL. If there's a way I can replicate the "Material" appearance in the default rendered view, that also works!

Thank you so so so much in advance, this has had me puzzled!

Comment: try setting "transparent" in the top-bar "render > opengl render options > alpha mode", you should get what you want... (default is "sky")

Comment: nice :) btw if you use viewport rendering, it is not cycles, nor blender render. just pure opengl, whatever shading the viewport has.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to render images or animations with a transparent background.

**Using *OpenGL* render :**

Make sure that you set the *Alpha mode* to *Transparent* in the Render > OpenGL Render Options > Alpha Mode which is located in the info header.

[image]

**Using *Blender Render :***

Make sure that you have set the *Alpha* to *Transparent* in the *Shading* option under the *Render* tab in the *Properties* panel.

[image]

**Using *Cycles render* :**

Make sure that you the *Transparency* ticked on in the *Film* option under the *Render* tab.

[image]